# C# Winforms program runs on one computer and not another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I wrote a program in C# for the place I work and as stated in the title, its working on one computer (my main work computer) but not on another (my spare work computer).

Here are the detail of the two computers:

My main computer, which I have local admin rights to and is the computer I used to create this program in Visual Studio 2015 Express, has these .NET Frameworks installed and the version I used on this program specifically. (I had to combine the two screenshots into one because I don't have enough reputation to attach more than 2 files):

[Main Computer .Net Frameworks Installed & Used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDmsX.png)

My spare computer I do NOT have admin rights to has these .NET Frameworks installed:

[Spare Computer .Net Frameworks Installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApdmO.png)

I used Visual Studio's built in Publish functionality on my main computer  to deploy this program to my spare computer, but when I try run the setup.exe, I get an error that creates this output:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.17929
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)
SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Local%20Files/Temp/QTC%20251.1%20Data%20Verification%20Tool.application
    Application url         : file:///C:/Local%20Files/Temp/Application%20Files/QTC%20251.1%20Data%20Verification%20Tool_1_0_0_0/QTC%20251.1%20Data%20Verification%20Tool.exe.manifest
IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : QTC 251.1 Data Verification Tool.application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2223067c4825c23a, processorArchitecture=msil
    Application Identity        : QTC 251.1 Data Verification Tool.exe, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2223067c4825c23a, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32
APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Local Files\Temp\QTC 251.1 Data Verification Tool.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Failed to load the runtime. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131700)
COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.
WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.
OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [4/12/2016 11:28:21 AM] : Activation of C:\Local Files\Temp\QTC 251.1 Data Verification Tool.application has started.
    * [4/12/2016 11:28:21 AM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [4/12/2016 11:28:21 AM] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [4/12/2016 11:28:21 AM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [4/12/2016 11:28:23 AM] : Found compatible runtime version 4.0.30319.
    * [4/12/2016 11:28:23 AM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.
    * [4/12/2016 11:28:24 AM] : Downloading of subscription dependencies is complete.
    * [4/12/2016 11:28:24 AM] : Commit of the downloaded application has started.
ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [4/12/2016 11:28:24 AM] System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        - Failed to load the runtime. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131700)
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.GetRequestedRuntimeInfo(String pExe, String pwszVersion, String pConfigurationFile, UInt32 startupFlags, UInt32 runtimeInfoFlags, StringBuilder pDirectory, UInt32 dwDirectory, UInt32& dwDirectoryLength, StringBuilder pVersion, UInt32 cchBuffer, UInt32& dwLength)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Win32InterOp.SystemUtils.CheckSupportedImageAndCLRVersions(String path)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CheckApplicationPayload(CommitApplicationParams commitParams)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CommitApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, CommitApplicationParams commitParams)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

After doing some Google searching, I believe this is telling me there's a problem with the .NET Framework the program was created with and the version on the spare computer, but they're both 4.5, so I don't know how to fix it.

I don't understand why these two different .NET Framework 4.5's don't work together.

Is there a way for me to fix this so that it will work on my spare computer and a handful of other computers at my work WITHOUT needing to install anything?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are not keeping that spare computer updated.  It has a very old version of .NET 4.5, the very first one.  There have been a lot of maintenance and security fixes released since then.  It is not otherwise obvious which exact version you targeted in your project.  Turn on Windows Update to let it do its job.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I wish I could... the software on this computer gets pushed by and is controlled by the IT department where I work.

Comment: Well, obviously it is their job to keep machines updated. Like they did with your main machine. Use a telephone or a "support ticket".  While you are at it, ask tor a proper license for VS, pretty ridiculous for a professional programmer to have to use a freeware edition, it is a license violation.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to get this one computer updated to the latest .NET 4.5 and see if that fixes it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: And, yeah, we are planning on getting me a license. I'm in a unique situation where I'm programming while being in a non-IT position, so we want to make sure someone on my position (with limited rights)will be able to create simple programs to help people be more productive. This is the pilot project to make sure its feasible before we get in too deep.

Comment: Just an "aside" comment - there's this tool which statically links your .net program, so that you can avoid these issues... (http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/). Also was watching a very interesting video showing Microsoft working on same kind of technology. Hope it becomes mainstream soon...!

Comment: There are **plenty** of google results (and stackoverflow) if you search either `0x80131700` or `Failed to load the runtime`. It's either a version/package mismatch, or the second computer has only the Client Profile.

Comment: @Jcl yeah, I did some google/stackoverflow searching, but I didn't find any results that clued me into it being a problem with a different SUB version of .NET 4.5. I was under the impression that 4.5 was 4.5.